# What does this mean in the definition of CW complex?

Tags: algebraic-topology

On [wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/CW_complex), in the definition of CW complex, it states that

> A subset of X is closed if and only if it meets the closure of each cell in a closed set.

What does this mean? I don't need an intuitive explanation or anything, I just literally don't know what it means. Does "meet" mean their intersection is nonempty? And "a closed set", what does that refer to? Literally an arbitrary closed set?

Comment: It means the intersection of the subset with the closure of each cell is closed. (The intersection could be empty...which is closed.)

Answer (score 2):

$K$ is closed if for each cell $e_k$, we have $K \cap \overline{e_k}$ is closed.

Answer (score 1):

It means that a subset $C\subseteq X$ is closed if and only if $C\cap e$ is closed for any closed cell $e$. Note that the notion of "closed cell" (as in image of glueing map) and "closure of (open) cell" coincide.